# Extract concontours from S57 features stored in SQLite3 file

Tags: python, gdal, sqlite, bathymetry, s-57

I have a table where one of the columns is a set of S57 objects given as a data buffer (FEATURE field):

```
    OBJ_ID          CHART_FID   FEATURE
0   441153270841366 102714      [, M, _, C, O, V, R, *, , , , , , , , ...
1   441153270841349 102714      [, C, B, L, S, U, B, , Q, , , , , , , ...
2   441153270841348 102714      [, C, B, L, S, U, B, , Q, , , , , , , ...
3   441153270841351 102714      [, D, E, P, C, N, T, 2, , , , , , , , ...
... ... ... ...
```

I would like to know how to decipher the information of each row/cell, specifically I intend to extract the data of bathymetric contours that are housed in it. I have found documentation in GDAL, QGIS and ArcGIS to represent S57 files with extension .000, however what I need is to interpret each S57 object individually.

After much review of the IHO documentation I have not been able to carry out the task, what I have been able to see more or less are the cells that correspond to what I intend to extract in the following way:

```
filter_cells = []
for index, row in table.iterrows():
   cell = row['FEATURE']
   if 'DEPCNT' in str(cell):
       filter_cells.append(cell)
```

An example of what I get when printing one of the filtered cells and therefore the information I need to decrypt would be:

```
>>>print(filtered[0])
DEPCNT2:�14+nZ@�@
```

However I am stuck on how to get the xyz coordinates.

Clarification: the table is part of a larger file with much more information, for anyone who wants the complete file, put it in a comment and I'll send you a download link.